# What SpanChat Lenses / MSQRD Filters are made of?

Tags: ios, augmented-reality, scenekit

I know there has been discussions on how to achieve SnapChat like filters but my question is not related to them.

I'd like to know how to render an overlay like SnapChat filters onto the screen and how to create these filters.

My first though is that these filter has been created in any 3D app and imported as COLLADA to sceneKit or openGL. But what I do not understand is how to position the left and right eye exactly on the corresponding positions that is designated by the API.

I have the location of left eye and the right eye, and I designed two separate eyes and positioned them on the scene but since they are two different node, they move about separately and this gives and impression of unrealistic experience to the user.

Another solution could be design one SCNode with eyes as child node of the rootNode and position them accordingly but I am not sure that is the right solution to it.

Any suggestions ?